# need Manufacturer with logo and description in opncart

Tags: opencart

I need help in OpenCart.

When somebody click on manufacturer he will get all the products for that brand. I want to show brand with it's logo and small description. Right now OpenCart is giving me only these options to add - manufacturer's:

- name
- image
- store
- SEO Keyword
- sort order

I need an option to add some description about the manufacturer with present options:

- Manufacturer Name:
- Manufacturer Profile/Description:
- Stores: Default
- SEO Keyword: Do not use spaces instead replace spaces with - and make sure the keyword is globally unique.
- Image: Browse  |  Clear
- Sort Order:

Comment: [And You have tried so far ... ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Here goes the similar link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623719/opencart-country-of-manufacturer/20626219#20626219

hope this helps