# Opencart country of manufacturer

Tags: php, opencart

How do you create an additional field (dropdown) in the manufacturer's edit page. I need it to add a manufacturer country. I searched the web a lot, but I didn't find any information or documentation.

Comment: This is not a programming question and should be asked on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a long procedure i can only explain the steps, as you know Opencart is MVC based so you have to go through each portion.

In Language of admin catalog/manufacturer.php
add new required variable to display label.

Controller of Admin catalog/manufacturer.php

```
getForm() //update regarding view variables according to tpl.
```

View file  of admin catalog/manufacturer_form.tpl
add your dropdown field and variables passed from getForm().

Controller of Admin catalog/manufacturer.php

```
validate() //check if you need validation on passed values from tpl file.
```

Now alter table manufacturer add extra field on database.

Model of Admin catalog/manufacturer.php

```
addManufacturer() //edit query to add your extra to insert in database
editManufacturer() //edit query to update your extra added field
```